# During boot my ubuntu box switches into graphic mode, but there is no window manager installed. How can I disable this?

Tags: boot, grub2, display-manager

Grub gives me two options, boot Ubuntu and boot Ubuntu Rescue Mode (or something alike). When I boot Ubuntu, I get to the point where dmesg gives green timestamps, but just before a login prompt would appear (I assume), it switches into graphics mode and subsequently sends my monitor into sleep mode, as there is no desktop environment installed.

I can access the box vie ssh, though, where it works as expected.
When I boot into Rescue Mode, it will present me with a prompt, whether I want to continue booting. When I confirm, I will get the login prompt. But this requires my interaction - what I want is boot to a text login prompt without any neediness for my attention.

In grub2 config `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` is set.

Anyone can tell from this information, what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You could edit `/etc/default/grub` and change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash 3"
```

to start the system in runlevel 3 instead of the default runlevel 5 (GUI).

Then update your grub configuration with

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is using `systemd` by now. To change the default mode at boot, use

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

To go back to graphical mode as default, use

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```